# How do I make a shortcut key do different things depending on the active tab page?

Tags: delphi, button, toolbar, hotkeys, ttabsheet

Each `TTabSheet` on my `TPageControl` has a `TToolBar` on it. Each tool bar has a `TToolButton` that should respond to the same keyboard shortcut. How do I provide hotkeys so that the right button is invoked for the current page?

On the first tab sheet, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> should make something happen, but upon switching to the second tab, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> should make something else happen instead.

Is this a time to toggle `TActionList.State` between `asNormal` and `asSuspended` when tab sheets are shown or hidden?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite follow you. TabSheets don't have tool buttons. Toolbars have tool buttons. Could you be more specific in what you are asking?

Comment: The way I habitually associate tool button actions to keyboard shortcuts is to use actions and assign a shortcut to the action. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: @mafax: no it is not; your question is still a mixup of ToolBar and TabSheet. Now: what are you really after?

Comment: -1; it really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> simply to flip between active `TabSheets` on a `PageControl`, then create a single **Action**, with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut, and flip between pages as required:

```
procedure TForm1.actNextPageExecute(Sender: TObject)
var
   nextPageIndex: Integer;
begin
   nextPageIndex := PageControl1.ActivePageIndex+1;

   if (nextPageIndex > PageControl1.Pages.Count-1) then
       nextPageIndex := 0;

   PageControl1.ActivePageIndex := nextPageIndex;
end;
```

Comment: No no, I wrote, I need shortscuts for ToolButtons (ToolBar). Each TabSheet has one ToolBar. ToolButtons on TabSheet1 and TabSheet2 can have the same shortcuts (Ctrl+T).

Comment: ActionToolBars and an ActionManager do seem to be the answer to this just need to manage the action shortcuts depending on which tab is showing

Answer (score 0):

If you want one TAction to do different things depending on what control initiated it, just look at the action's `ActionComponent` property. Hook all the controls to the same action.

An alternative would be to have multiple actions with the same shortcut and enable or disable them in the Update event based on what is visible or focused.